Error: EACCES: permission denied: Writing to the mounted volume from nextjs app
I have a nextjs app and a dotnet8 app running in docker with one docker-compose file. Here are my files:
The nextjs/Dockerfile:
FROM node:20.15.0-alpine3.20 AS base

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=ext_path somefile somefile

COPY package*.json ./
RUN mkdir node_modules
RUN npm install --no-audit --omit=dev
RUN npm install sharp

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=deps /app/.env.local ./.env.local
COPY . .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

COPY --from=deps /app/.env.local ./.env.local
COPY --from=ext_path somefile somefile

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.mjs ./next.config.mjs

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

RUN mkdir -p ./public/v1/uploads
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs ./public/v1/uploads

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 80

ENV PORT 80
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "server.js"]

And the dotnet8/Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

USER app
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine AS build
ARG configuration=Release

COPY ["MyApp.sln", "MyApp.sln"]
COPY ["MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]

RUN dotnet restore "MyApp.sln"

COPY MyApp/ MyApp/

WORKDIR "/MyApp"

FROM build AS publish
ARG configuration=Release
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]

The production/docker.env file:
SRV_NAME=myproject

DOCKER_ENV=production
RUNTIME_ENV=production

WEB_EXPOSE_PORT=4000
API_EXPOSE_PORT=4100

UPLOAD_MOUNT_PATH=/var/lib/MyApp/web/public/v1/uploads

And finally the docker-compose.yml file:
networks:
    default:
        name: ${SRV_NAME}_default
        external: false
    infra:
        name: infra
        external: true
        driver: bridge

services:
    my-web:
        container_name: ${SRV_NAME}-web
        image: jd/my-web:latest
        hostname: ${SRV_NAME}-web
        depends_on:
            - my-api
        build:
            context: ./nextjs
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
            network: host
            args:
                NODE_ENV: ${RUNTIME_ENV}
            additional_contexts:
                ext_path: ./${DOCKER_ENV}/ # This is just for reading some additional resources.
        volumes:
            - ${UPLOAD_MOUNT_PATH}:/app/public/v1/uploads:rw
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=${RUNTIME_ENV}
        ports:
            - ${WEB_EXPOSE_PORT}:80
        networks:
            default:
            infra:

    my-api:
        container_name: ${SRV_NAME}-api
        image: jd/my-api:latest
        hostname: ${SRV_NAME}-api
        build:
            context: ./dotnet8
            dockerfile: ./MyApp/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ${UPLOAD_MOUNT_PATH}:/app/public/v1/uploads:rw
        ports:
            - ${API_EXPOSE_PORT}:80
        networks:
            default:
            infra:

So, I'm trying to save an uploaded file from nextjs app. But I'm getting this error:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/public/v1/uploads/639ceeac-65f3-4726-8a31-9e55e603ff9b.png'
    at async open (node:internal/fs/promises:639:25)
    at async writeFile (node:internal/fs/promises:1219:14)
    at async c (/app/.next/server/chunks/106.js:1:21544)
    at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:418
    at async rP (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:15:7978)
    at async r9 (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:18:1139)
    at async doRender (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1438:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1599:28)
    at async NextNodeServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1507:28)
    at async NextNodeServer.renderPageComponent (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1931:24) {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/app/public/v1/uploads/639ceeac-65f3-4726-8a31-9e55e603ff9b.png'
}

So have you any idea what's wrong here? And how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.
PS. I'm not looking for kind of solutions that need actions after running the containers - e.g. changing the mounted volume's permission from host or going into the container and giving permission to the path etc.
I think the correct solution is the solution contained in Dockerfile or docker-compose.

give this folder permission 755 : /app/public/v1/uploads
to give permission go into docker and give the permission

If you're using a bind-mounted host directory, you might need to set both containers to run as a user: that can access the directory.  That will depend on the host setup, and it's not something you can fix from the Dockerfile.  Does Docker-compose set user and group on mounted volume address your problem?
